# How do I edit script in embedded code within a web part (content editor after pasting in an invalid script)?

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I have added an incorrect script text/URL into the embedded Code of a web part content editor.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://spfarm.rootname.com/sites/SITENAME/SitePages/Home.aspx">
```

Now, the site URL fails (The webpage cannot be found)
I forgot how to get back into edit to fix ! I am only a tester not a developer, however, I do have all access rights.

Comment: Hi @User62105, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange community. we don't use salutations or signatures here like we do in other forums. Happy StackExchanging, :).

Answer (score 1):

Try appending "?Contents=1" to your site's URL to put the homepage into a special web part maintenance view. You can find and delete your snippet/content editor from there.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on (Settings) icon > Click Edit Page

[image]

- Find the content editor web part in your page  >Click on it.
- From the above ribbon > at Format Text tab > Click on `Edit Source`

**Note:** If it's a script editor web part , just after editing the page click `edit snippet`