# Removing Weekend Days From Calendar as web part

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-calendar, script

I wish to edit my 2013 Calendar web part and remove Saturday and Sunday from showing if possible so it only shows the work days of the week. 
I've tried the scripts shared on this tread:
[Removing Weekend Days From Calendar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83372/removing-weekend-days-from-calendar)

The first one works, but only in the calendar itself, not when you add calendar as web part to another page.

For the second one, I get an error saying: "Warning: Some of your markup was stripped out. Try using the Embed command."

Anyone??

Comment: I don't know this from experience, but I just searched on "embed script" and found this, maybe it's useful: [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200472/how-do-i-edit-script-in-embedded-code-within-a-web-part-content-editor-after-pa)

Comment: Thanks, @Tally. I've already found how to emded scripts. But when I copy the script for the view, that's were the error pop up